# PHP json_encode SOMETIMES returns "null" as value from a database query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When making a SELECT query from a database, sometimes, I get a null value on the text field. It seems random, but usually after I update the database this issue seems to follow. Following is my code:

```
require_once('database.php');

$sql = "SELECT stories.id, authors.name AS author, authors.dates AS dates, authors.life AS life, stories.title AS title, stories.text AS text, stories.summary AS summary, stories.reading_time AS time, stories.cost AS cost, stories.file_name AS story_filename, category.name AS category
FROM stories
INNER JOIN category ON stories.category_id = category.id
INNER JOIN authors ON stories.author_id = authors.id";

if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
 $resultArray = array();
 $tempArray = array();

while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
 $tempArray = $row;
 array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
}
echo json_encode($resultArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

The error happens on the text field. It comes as

```
text = "<null>";
```

The other fields are fine.

I appreciate any help on this! Thanks

Comment: checking on the browser? most likely the browser `<null>` mixed it up just like tags

Comment: Thanks for responding, but the problem is on the json response to an app that uses this code to connect to the database. The app is using Swift 2.0 and the json retrieved from this code sometimes (after any update to the database) has the <null> value.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
My solution was to change the text field attribute in the database from utf8_general_ci to asci_bin.

regards